# having difficulty installing web3 on ubuntu 16.04 using node 9.11.1 and npm 5.6.0 (for Solidity development)

Tags: npm, solidity, ubuntu-16.04, web3js

> npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with
> Promise Support npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7:   WARNING  tar.gz
> module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please
> use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar
>
> > scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall /home/eschulton/code/solidity/inbox/node_modules/scrypt
> > node node-scrypt-preinstall.js
>
> > scrypt@6.0.3 install /home/eschulton/code/solidity/inbox/node_modules/scrypt
> > node-gyp rebuild
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/eschulton/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py",
> line 13, in 
> import gyp   File "/home/eschulton/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/**init**.py",
> line 8, in 
> import gyp.input   File "/home/eschulton/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py",
> line 5, in 
> from compiler.ast import Const ImportError: No module named compiler.ast gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp`
> failed with exit code: 1 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit
> (/home/eschulton/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:336:16)
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13) gyp ERR!
> stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (internal/child_process.js:209:12) gyp ERR! System Linux
> 4.4.0-119-generic gyp ERR! command "/home/eschulton/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/bin/node"
> "/home/eschulton/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
> "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd
> /home/eschulton/code/solidity/inbox/node_modules/scrypt gyp ERR! node
> -v v9.11.1 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2 gyp ERR! not ok npm WARN inbox@1.0.0 No description npm WARN inbox@1.0.0 No repository field.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3
> install: `node-gyp rebuild` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!
> Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script. npm ERR! This is probably
> not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
> above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /home/eschulton/.npm/_logs/2018-04-06T23_06_20_693Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

incorrect prerequisite:

```
sudo apt-get install python-minimal
```

correct prerequisite:

```
sudo apt-get install python
```